# Convert UUID to CSUUID mongoDB

Tags: javascript, .net, mongodb, studio3t

I try create new CSUUID column as _id, usually I can do in Studio 3T it with javascript in $addFields aggregation:

```
function: 
{
    "_id": {
        $function: {
            body: function() {
                return UUID();
            },
            args: [],
            lang: "js"
        }
    }
}
```

But this code generates normal GUID (UUID) not .NET UUID. Since our collection uses .NET UUID I need to generate in my aggregation script .NET UUID, but it generates UUID:

[image]

Do you know a solution how to solve it?